# After build APK, data from API doesn't appear in expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo

After successfully developing and testing my app on an emulator with `Expo`, I proceeded to build an `APK` using the EAS build service. However, upon downloading and running the `APK` on my mobile device, I encountered an issue: `the app was not able to fetch data from the API`. I use `Axios` for network calls.

This issue is perplexing as the app works seamlessly on the emulator, but the API calls fail in the standalone `APK`. I'm seeking guidance on how to debug this problem effectively after building the `APK`.

I appreciate any assistance and advice you can provide

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether you have added the internet permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

If your API URL is not SSL certified, then you need to enable http traffic as it get's blocked by Android on physical device but works fine on emulators. Add this line inside your `<application/>` tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```